# VS Code Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]

Tags: python, node.js, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use the python library `XCUBE` in VS Code

Hving followed the instructions here https://github.com/dcs4cop/xcube-viewer for `xcube-viewer`, I have just tried the command `yarn start` and gotten the below error:

```
yarn run v1.22.19
$ react-scripts start
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:535
      throw e;
      ^

Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/tokenize' is not defined by "exports" in c:\XCUBE\xcube-viewer\node_modules\postcss-safe-parser\node_modules\postcss\package.json
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
    at throwExportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:358:9)
    at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:668:3)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:529:36)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:569:31)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\XCUBE\xcube-viewer\node_modules\postcss-safe-parser\lib\safe-parser.js:1:17) {
  code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
}

Node.js v18.12.1
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

The repository is up to date, so I am not sure why the issue is occuring?

Comment: It happened to me once and this helped: 
https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/node-error-err-package-path-not-exported
Have you tried looking at it ?